# Python Requests - BadStatusLine('Content-type: text/html\r\n')

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm currently working with the CSGO Gamestate Integration ([Info Here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Game_State_Integration#External_links)) to gather data. Essentially I start an HTTP server to handle POST requests from the game. What I need, is to send a POST request from a different Python script to sync the data with another operation I am doing. Basically, just need the server to recognize that it received the packet, but I'm receiving an HTTP error.

Code for HTTP Server POST method:

```
def do_POST(self):
    length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
    body = self.rfile.read(length).decode('utf-8')

    print(pprint.pprint(self.responses))

    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
    self.end_headers()

    self.parse_frameSync_payload(json.loads(body))
```

Code for Request POST:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36'}

try:
    r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000', json={'auth': 'frameSync'}, headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
    print('frameSync: \t\tConnection Refused.')
```

Output from HTTP Server when Request is run:

```
  {<HTTPStatus.CONTINUE: 100>: ('Continue', 'Request received, please continue'),
     <HTTPStatus.SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS: 101>: ('Switching Protocols',
                                         'Switching to new protocol; obey '
                                         'Upgrade header'),
     <HTTPStatus.PROCESSING: 102>: ('Processing', ''),
     <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>: ('OK', 'Request fulfilled, document follows'),
     <HTTPStatus.CREATED: 201>: ('Created', 'Document created, URL follows'),
     <HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED: 202>: ('Accepted',
                              'Request accepted, processing continues '
                              'off-line'),
     <HTTPStatus.NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION: 203>: ('Non-Authoritative '
                                                   'Information',
                                                   'Request fulfilled from '
                                                   'cache'),
     <HTTPStatus.NO_CONTENT: 204>: ('No Content',
                                'Request fulfilled, nothing follows'),
     <HTTPStatus.RESET_CONTENT: 205>: ('Reset Content',
                                   'Clear input form for further input'),
     <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>: ('Partial Content',
                                     'Partial content follows'),
     <HTTPStatus.MULTI_STATUS: 207>: ('Multi-Status', ''),
     <HTTPStatus.ALREADY_REPORTED: 208>: ('Already Reported', ''),
     <HTTPStatus.IM_USED: 226>: ('IM Used', ''),
     <HTTPStatus.MULTIPLE_CHOICES: 300>: ('Multiple Choices',
                                      'Object has several resources -- see URI '
                                      'list'),
     <HTTPStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY: 301>: ('Moved Permanently',
                                       'Object moved permanently -- see URI '
                                       'list'),
     <HTTPStatus.FOUND: 302>: ('Found', 'Object moved temporarily -- see URI list'),
     <HTTPStatus.SEE_OTHER: 303>: ('See Other',
                               'Object moved -- see Method and URL list'),
     <HTTPStatus.NOT_MODIFIED: 304>: ('Not Modified',
                                  'Document has not changed since given time'),
     <HTTPStatus.USE_PROXY: 305>: ('Use Proxy',
                               'You must use proxy specified in Location to '
                               'access this resource'),
     <HTTPStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT: 307>: ('Temporary Redirect',
                                        'Object moved temporarily -- see URI '
                                        'list'),
 <HTTPStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT: 308>: ('Permanent Redirect',
                                        'Object moved temporarily -- see URI '
                                        'list'),
 <HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST: 400>: ('Bad Request',
                                 'Bad request syntax or unsupported method'),
 <HTTPStatus.UNAUTHORIZED: 401>: ('Unauthorized',
                                  'No permission -- see authorization schemes'),
 <HTTPStatus.PAYMENT_REQUIRED: 402>: ('Payment Required',
                                      'No payment -- see charging schemes'),
 <HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN: 403>: ('Forbidden',
                               'Request forbidden -- authorization will not '
                               'help'),
 <HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND: 404>: ('Not Found', 'Nothing matches the given URI'),
 <HTTPStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED: 405>: ('Method Not Allowed',
                                        'Specified method is invalid for this '
                                        'resource'),
 <HTTPStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE: 406>: ('Not Acceptable',
                                    'URI not available in preferred format'),
 <HTTPStatus.PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED: 407>: ('Proxy Authentication '
                                                   'Required',
                                                   'You must authenticate with '
                                                   'this proxy before '
                                                   'proceeding'),
 <HTTPStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT: 408>: ('Request Timeout',
                                     'Request timed out; try again later'),
 <HTTPStatus.CONFLICT: 409>: ('Conflict', 'Request conflict'),
 <HTTPStatus.GONE: 410>: ('Gone',
                          'URI no longer exists and has been permanently '
                          'removed'),
 <HTTPStatus.LENGTH_REQUIRED: 411>: ('Length Required',
                                     'Client must specify Content-Length'),
 <HTTPStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED: 412>: ('Precondition Failed',
                                         'Precondition in headers is false'),
 <HTTPStatus.REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE: 413>: ('Request Entity Too Large',
                                              'Entity is too large'),
 <HTTPStatus.REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG: 414>: ('Request-URI Too Long',
                                          'URI is too long'),
 <HTTPStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE: 415>: ('Unsupported Media Type',
                                            'Entity body in unsupported '
                                            'format'),
 <HTTPStatus.REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE: 416>: ('Requested Range Not '
                                                     'Satisfiable',
                                                     'Cannot satisfy request '
                                                     'range'),
 <HTTPStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED: 417>: ('Expectation Failed',
                                        'Expect condition could not be '
                                        'satisfied'),
 <HTTPStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY: 422>: ('Unprocessable Entity', ''),
 <HTTPStatus.LOCKED: 423>: ('Locked', ''),
 <HTTPStatus.FAILED_DEPENDENCY: 424>: ('Failed Dependency', ''),
 <HTTPStatus.UPGRADE_REQUIRED: 426>: ('Upgrade Required', ''),
 <HTTPStatus.PRECONDITION_REQUIRED: 428>: ('Precondition Required',
                                           'The origin server requires the '
                                           'request to be conditional'),
 <HTTPStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS: 429>: ('Too Many Requests',
                                       'The user has sent too many requests in '
                                       'a given amount of time ("rate '
                                       'limiting")'),
 <HTTPStatus.REQUEST_HEADER_FIELDS_TOO_LARGE: 431>: ('Request Header Fields '
                                                     'Too Large',
                                                     'The server is unwilling '
                                                     'to process the request '
                                                     'because its header '
                                                     'fields are too large'),
 <HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: 500>: ('Internal Server Error',
                                           'Server got itself in trouble'),
 <HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED: 501>: ('Not Implemented',
                                     'Server does not support this operation'),
 <HTTPStatus.BAD_GATEWAY: 502>: ('Bad Gateway',
                                 'Invalid responses from another server/proxy'),
 <HTTPStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE: 503>: ('Service Unavailable',
                                         'The server cannot process the '
                                         'request due to a high load'),
 <HTTPStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT: 504>: ('Gateway Timeout',
                                     'The gateway server did not receive a '
                                     'timely response'),
 <HTTPStatus.HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED: 505>: ('HTTP Version Not Supported',
                                                'Cannot fulfill request'),
 <HTTPStatus.VARIANT_ALSO_NEGOTIATES: 506>: ('Variant Also Negotiates', ''),
 <HTTPStatus.INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE: 507>: ('Insufficient Storage', ''),
 <HTTPStatus.LOOP_DETECTED: 508>: ('Loop Detected', ''),
 <HTTPStatus.NOT_EXTENDED: 510>: ('Not Extended', ''),
 <HTTPStatus.NETWORK_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED: 511>: ('Network Authentication '
                                                     'Required',
                                                     'The client needs to '
                                                     'authenticate to gain '
                                                     'network access')}
```

Comment: That `responses` attributes is of no help at all, removing it will reduce the noise in your question.

Comment: Ok. I'm assuming that error is only because a requests object is never created due to the POST failure. Would that be correct?

Comment: Your server is sending the `Content-Type` header **before** the status code. I'm unfamiliar with the technology so this is a shot in the dark. Switch the `send_header` and `send_response` calls

Comment: Greatly appreciate the fast replies. I'll give it a shot and report back.               Edit: It seems that the 200 response is now sent allowing the request script to continue running without error but the HTTP error still persists.